# Reset a USB Modem without physical access (KVM virtual machine)

Tags: usb, restart, kvm-virtualization, usb-modem

I'm using a USB-modem to connect a virtual machine with the internet. So host and guest do not share the same IP/network. I emulate by `qemu-kvm`, device forwarding works great with `*-usb -usbdevice host:1c9e:9603*`. The VM uses Ubuntu 10.04, Host 11.10.

Unfortunately the modem unmounts after ~3 days. Obviously, from now on no connection can be established. After the VM reboots, a connection is possible again.

`nmcli` can be used to establish an internet connection and check whether its still active. 
But how do I remount the device/modem with a small bash script?

The syslog below shows how the device unplugs after being ~3 days in use:

```
pppd[1369]: LCP terminated by peer
pppd[1369]: Connect time 1104.9 minutes.
pppd[1369]: Sent 1279 bytes, received 790 bytes.
kernel: [66423.705380] device ppp0 left promiscuous mode

pppd[1369]: Modem hangup
pppd[1369]: Connection terminated.

avahi-daemon[424]: Withdrawing workstation service for ppp0.
modem-manager[483]: <info>  (ttyUSB2) closing serial port...

NetworkManager[431]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
NetworkManager[431]: <info> (ttyUSB2): now unmanaged
NetworkManager[431]: <info> (ttyUSB2): device state change: 8 -> 1 (reason 36)
NetworkManager[431]: <info> (ttyUSB2): deactivating device (reason: 36).
NetworkManager[431]: <warn> could not read ppp stats: No such device
NetworkManager[431]: <info> (ttyUSB2): cleaning up...
NetworkManager[431]: <info> (ttyUSB2): taking down device.
NetworkManager[431]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)

nm-dispatcher.action: Error in get_property: Method "Get" with signature "ss" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist#012
modem-manager[483]: <info>  (ttyUSB2) serial port closed
modem-manager[483]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/0: state changed (connected -> disconnecting)
modemqemu-kvm-manager[483]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/0: state changed (disconnecting -> connected)

pppd[1369]: Exit.
NetworkManager[431]: <info> disconnect failed: (32) The serial port is not open.
```

I am afraid, that restarting these USB-daemons on the VM will not be enough - as I will have to tell the qemuKVM-Manager to forward the device once again. But that would be the second step.

Comment: Are you saying that the USB device disappears from the guest after 3 days? If so, it's a bug, and it could easily be on either side. Like the USB device could encounter an error condition, perform a bus reset, and that reset takes it offline. All you're seeing from the VM + passthrough is the device in unavailable. My gut tells me this may be a USB powersave issue, or a flaky USB device. This old external USR serial modems are good for something, rock solid reliability, and real serial ports usually don't have bus reset problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this http://marc.info/?l=linux-usb&m=121459435621262&w=2 c-programm to reset usb.

```
$ cc usbreset.c -o usbreset
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0fe9:9010 DVICO
$ chmod +x usbreset
$ sudo ./usbreset /dev/bus/usb/002/003
```

The UMTS Modem disappears for ~20 secs and appears again in the VM.
Fortunately, it is redirected automatically by the qemu manager!

The problem is still *NOT* solved, as after 3 days even this usb reset will not allow me to establish a well-functioning connection.

A reboot of the VM is my last resort...

**@ppetraki:**

> The modem does not disappear from the network manager, its
>   still there, no connection can be established though.

Comment: Remember, this is just a serial port. In your VM you should be able to find it in /dev as a plan ttySn or ttyUSBSn device. If you can't chat with it with minicom, kermit, or wvdial, it doesn't matter what NM thinks as it might be working with a stale handle. You need to verify that the serial device is actually responding, open it with minicom and enter `AT` and press enter, if you don't see an `OK` then you have more troubleshooting to do. See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Modem-HOWTO/#s8